# Redirecting to an internal page if logged in (Redirect Loop Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, redirect

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help.

My goal is that when a someone goes to the front page of the site I am building is logged in, they get forwarded to another page (the same page people go to after manually logging in)

Here is my code to do this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/inside.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

The c# code for inside.aspx is currently empty. But if the user is logged in I get a redirect loop error when in the browser. I am not sure why.

Followed is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!--<roleManager enabled="true" />-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="default.aspx" defaultUrl="inside.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=SCRUMAPIUI;User Id=tunnelld;Password=PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting a redirect loop? How can I get the default page of my site to forward to another page correctly if the user is logged in?

EDIT:

Here is the error being displayed in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: what is the exact text of the error?

Comment: Can you post any `<authorization>` sections from your web.config?

Comment: also, try `Response.Redirect("~/inside.aspx", false);`  If that doesn't work, what browser are you on?  Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: I added the exact error message as an image, adding false as a parameter didn't work, the <authorization> section is shown above.

Comment: are you sure that the user is authenticated by the time the reach `inside.aspx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the CodeFile reference for both files was the same. Silly mistake but if you have this problem make sure to check it!

Answer (score 2):

The loop I see is:

- A person goes to Default.aspx and they are already "logged in".
- Your code redirects them to inside.aspx
- In transit, they lose authentication (which may or may not be due to the browser).
- Your web.config notices that they are in an inside page, but not authenticated!
- your web.config pushes them back out to Default.aspx, where, for whatever reason, you are still authenticated.
- Your code redirects them to inside.aspx.

etc.

As good practice, make sure the user that is authenticated is not the anonymous user.  That could be what is tripping you up.

Is there any chance you are using IE 10 to test this?

Comment: I've been using Chrome, how would I check that the user authenticated is not an anonymous user? Thanks.

Comment: I forget exactly what to check for, but it's going to be `HttpContext.Current.User`-related.  Possibly `.Name`?  Play around with it a bit.  Also, if you are using cookies, make sure that the cookie is persistent and behaving like you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the configuration section of webconfig..

```
<location path="default.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

And add this just below your existing closing `</authentication>` tags to prevent access to any other pages unless authenticated.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" /> 
</authorization>
```